# 800a01b8|OIP-04148:_Unable_to_obtain_a_free_database_object_from_the_pool

Tags: iis, asp-classic, oracle11g, windows-server-2003

Yesterday we had ODAC (ODTwithODAC1120320_32bit) installation in our server. 
Server had classic ASP and ASP.NET applications.

Today, Suddenly we experience Oracle connections pile up and its not releasing the connections.

- Server : Windows 2003
- No of users : 6
- We have both 10g and 11g clients installed.
- Application pool has only this application in IIS.
- Connections will reach its max count within 4 minutes after
  application pool recycle in IIS.
- 100 max connections, Tried increasing max limit to 400 from 100 connections, same
  behavior.
- 60 secs timeout for connections
- Three servers load balancing(F5) the load, still the connections are maxed out.
- Connections closing and record set closure already in place from code perspective.
- Application used to work till date from years.

Connections are retrieved from Global.asa as mentioned below.

```
<OBJECT RUNAT="Server" SCOPE="Application" ID="OraSession"     PROGID="OracleInProcServer.XOraSession"></OBJECT> 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBScript RUNAT=Server> 

Sub Application_OnStart 
    OraSession.CreateDatabasePool 6,100,60,"DBNAME", "Username/pwd", 0 
End Sub 

Sub Application_OnEnd 
    OraSession.destroydatabasepool()
End Sub 
</Script>
```

Connections made from ASP as below

```
strSelect = "SELECT * from table where status = 'SUCCESS'"
Set OraRecordSet = OraDatabase.DbCreateDynaset(strSelect, cint(0))
OraRecordSet.movefirst
    if OraRecordSet.RecordCount > 0 then
        do while OraRecordSet.eof = false
        OraRecordSet.movenext
        Loop
    end if
Call ClearDatabaseParams(OraDatabase)
OraRecordSet.close
OraDatabase.close
Set OraRecordSet = Nothing
Set OraDataBase = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue found to be missing reference(include) in this asp, where the ClearDatabaseParams function resides.

Since there was `On Error Resume Next` in the page beginning the error was not logging in W3SVC logs either.

Removing that records the `800a01f4|Variable_is_undefined:_'ClearDatabaseParams` error in the log file

After including the reference reference to that function issue resolved.